# Using properties of Cauchy sequence to prove uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

So I have a partial solution to the problem below but I reached a dead end that I'm hoping someone could assist me with.

Let $V$ be a complete normed vector space.

We will use $\|\cdot\|$ to indicate the norm on $V$.

Part i) Let $(f_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $C([a,b],V)$. Show that for each $x \in [a,b], (f_n(x))$ is Cauchy, and so define the pointwise limit $f(x) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$.

Solution: We know $\forall x \in [a,b], \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N$ such that if $m,n \geq N$, then $\|f_n(x) - f_m(x)\| < \epsilon$.

So let $x \in [a,b]$. Hence, $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N$ such that if $n \geq N$, then $\|f_n(x) - f_m(x)\| < \epsilon$.

This shows that $(f_n(x))$ is Cauchy in $V$. Since $V$ is complete, $(f_n(x))$ is convergent. Hence, we can define $f(x) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$.

I'm confident that I did this portion of the problem correctly, but I am not completely certain.

Part ii) Prove that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly. HINT: Use the Cauchy criterion to obtain an estimate for $\|f_n(x) - f(x)\|$ that is independent of the point $x$.

So I'm having a bit of trouble with this part.

So I know $\|f_n(x) - f(x)\| = \lim\limits_{m \to \infty}\|f_n(x) - f_m(x)\|$ but I don't know how to bound this by $\epsilon$.

Any help or corrections to the work I have done will be appreciated.

Comment: Should we assume that $\|f\|=\sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)|$ for $f \in C([a,b])$?

Comment: Going to be quite difficult to prove the sequence converges uniformly without having that it is uniformly Cauchy.

Comment: Well you have the right idea with $\|f_n(x) - f(x)\| = \lim\limits_{m \to \infty}\|f_n(x) - f_m(x)\|$. I am mainly concerned with the information you have stated for the problem. We want the norm to at least imply convergence in the $\sup$-norm which isn't the case for an arbitrary norm on $C([a,b])$. We also want these functions to be mapping into a complete metric space (such as $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: This is good but we are still going to somehow need that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that  $\|f_n(x)-f_m(x)\|< \epsilon$ whenever $m,n \geq N$ and $x \in [a,b]$. In other words, when you assume the sequence is Cauchy this should either mean or somehow imply that the sequence is uniformly Cauchy.

We don't need this for showing the functions have a pointwise limit, but we do need this to establish uniform convergence and have this pointwise limit $f \in C([a,b])$.

Comment: Convergence in the $\sup$-norm is uniform convergence. I suppose the fact that we have a norm which makes $C([a,b])$ a Banach space might mean that convergence in this norm implies uniform convergence but this is merely a guess as I simply know basic facts like $C([a,b])$ with the $L^1$ norm is not complete and convergence in $L^1$ doesn't imply uniform convergence. I would be interested to know what book you found this problem in as I surely can't clarify things further. Perhaps someone with more knowledge of functional analysis can from the info given here.

Answer (score 2):

If this is word-for-word what your question says, then if I have to make an educated guess, I would say we put the sup norm on $C([a,b],V)$. The way the question is phrased does indeed suggest that the objective is to prove that $C([a,b],V)$ with sup norm is a Banach space (and usually in my experience, if nothing else is said, this is the norm we consider on the space of continuous functions).

For any function $g:[a,b]\to V$, I shall write $\lVert g \rVert_{\infty}:= \sup_{x\in [a,b]}\lVert g(x)\rVert$, where $\lVert\cdot \rVert$ is the norm on $V$. Now, by definition of $(f_n)$ being Cauchy in $C([a,b],V)$ (with sup norm), given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N\in\Bbb{N}$ such that for all $m,n\geq N$, we have
\begin{align}
\lVert f_n-f_m\rVert_{\infty}\leq \epsilon.
\end{align}
Now, let $x\in [a,b]$ be arbitrary, and let $n\geq N$. Then,
\begin{align}
\lVert f_n(x)-f(x)\rVert&= \lVert f_n(x)-\lim_{m\to \infty}f_m(x)\rVert\\
&=\lim_{m\to \infty}\lVert f_n(x)-f_m(x)\rVert \tag{$*$}\\
&\leq \limsup_{m\to \infty}\lVert f_n-f_m \rVert_{\infty}
\end{align}
(by the way I put a $\limsup$ in the end because for a given $n$, $\lim_{m\to \infty}\lVert f_n-f_m\rVert_{\infty}$ need not exist, but the limit superior of a sequence of real numbers always exists).
Try to justify why you can pull the limit out in $(*)$. Now, can you finish up the proof that $f_n\to f$ uniformly (i.e $\lVert f_n-f \rVert_{\infty}\to 0$)?

Comment: @AdamSmithSings see my latest (technical) edit; but yes that's essentially it.